# I am getting the following errors when I debug my code.The debug might be that Mutate is taking the value of Classroom1

Tags: python

```
# Loop(Classroom1, m_count, h_count, t_count, l_count, loopsize)
  File "/Users/maninder/git/TrialScheduler/TrialScheduler/main.py", line 27, in Loop
    Loop(Classroom1, m_count, h_count, t_count, l_count, loopsize)
  File "/Users/maninder/git/TrialScheduler/TrialScheduler/main.py", line 27, in Loop
    Loop(Classroom1, m_count, h_count, t_count, l_count, loopsize)
   File "/Users/maninder/git/TrialScheduler/TrialScheduler/main.py", line 27, in Loop #
```

The code:

```
from CProfessor import Professor 
    from CCourse import Course
    from CClassroom import Classroom
    import copy
def Loop(Classroom1, m_count, h_count, t_count, l_count, loopsize):
    for i in range(0, loopsize):
        Mutated = Classroom()
        #Mutated = Classroom1.CopyOfClassroom(Mutated)
        Mutated = copy.deepcopy(Classroom1)#Modification
        Mutated.Mutate()
        HardConstraintClassroomMet = Classroom1.ComputeHardConstraint()
        HardConstraintMutatedMet = Mutated.ComputeHardConstraint()
        if HardConstraintClassroomMet == False and HardConstraintMutatedMet == False:
            h_count + 1
            t_count + 1
            Classroom1.Mutate()
            continue
        if Mutated.FitnessValue() > Classroom1.FitnessValue():
            m_count + 1
            t_count + 1
            Classroom1 = Mutated
        if Classroom1.ComputeHardConstraint() == False:
            l_count + 1
            temp = l_count*loopsize
            print "Unable to meet hard consraints in %d" % temp
        Loop(Classroom1, m_count, h_count, t_count, l_count, loopsize)

    Professor0 = Professor(ProfessorId = 0, PreferedStartTime = 8, PreferedEndTime = 11)
    Professor1 = Professor(ProfessorId = 1, PreferedStartTime  = 10, PreferedEndTime = 13.75)
    Professor2 = Professor(ProfessorId = 2, PreferedStartTime  = 4, PreferedEndTime = 7.75)

# intializing Courses
    Course0 = Course(CourseId = 0, ProfessorId = 0, CourseSlot = 0, CourseType ="UnderGraduate")
    Course1 = Course(CourseId = 1, ProfessorId = 4, CourseSlot = 1) # we decided to leave this 
coursetype to be emmpty and it is set none in the Course class
    Course2 = Course(CourseId = 2, ProfessorId = 1, CourseSlot = 2, CourseType ="UnderGraduate")
    Course3 = Course(CourseId = 3, ProfessorId = 4, CourseSlot = 3)
    Course4 = Course(CourseId = 4, ProfessorId = 1, CourseSlot = 4, CourseType ="UnderGraduate")
    Course5 = Course(CourseId = 5, ProfessorId = 4, CourseSlot = 5)
    Course6 = Course(CourseId = 6, ProfessorId = 2, CourseSlot = 6, CourseType ="Graduate")
    Course7 = Course(CourseId = 7, ProfessorId = 2, CourseSlot = 7, CourseType ="UnderGraduate")

# intializing 
    Classroom1 = Classroom(FirstCourseStartTime = 8, LastCourseEndTime = 7.75)
# Add all courses to Classroom1
    Classroom1.AddCourse(Course0)
    Classroom1.AddCourse(Course1)
    Classroom1.AddCourse(Course2)
    Classroom1.AddCourse(Course3)
    Classroom1.AddCourse(Course4)
    Classroom1.AddCourse(Course5)
    Classroom1.AddCourse(Course6)
    Classroom1.AddCourse(Course7)

# Add Professors to the classroom.

    Classroom1.AddProfessor(Professor0)
    Classroom1.AddProfessor(Professor1)
    Classroom1.AddProfessor(Professor2) 

    m_count = 0 # mutations caused by grea
    h_count = 0
    t_count = 0
    l_count = 0
    loopsize = 10000
    Loop(Classroom1, m_count, h_count, t_count, l_count, loopsize)
    """
    Printing out the results:
    """
    print '\n'
    print "Mutation caused by greater fitness value %d" % m_count
    print "Mutation caused by Hard Constraint Violations %d" % h_count
    print "Number of Mutations before Converging" % t_count
    Classroom1.PrintClassroom()
```

Comment: It looks like you tried to paste the error at the top, but it's truncated.  Also, you seem to have pasted way too much code.  Post the part of your code that has the problem, not a bunch of extraneous material.

Comment: Can you show the rest of the backtrace, or at least the actual error message? Is your code indented properly? If so, Loop calls itself loopsize times every time you call it, which is never going to end, so you'll run out of stack space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
def Loop(Classroom1, m_count, h_count, t_count, l_count, loopsize):
    for i in range(0, loopsize):
        Loop(Classroom1.Mutate(), m_count, h_count, t_count, l_count, loopsize)
```

In other words, when you call Loop with loopsize=10, it will call Loop 10 more times with loopsize 10… which will call Loop 100 more times… which will call it 1000 more times. So eventually, you're going to run out of stack space.

The only way you ever skip the recursive case is if Classroom1.ComputeHardConstraint(), in which case you skip over one call to Loop, but you've still got loopcount-1 other calls. A properly-defined algorithm might complete, but it seems like you're diverging—you cut off successful branches of the recursion tree, but continue on the rest forever. And even if it does converge, the recursion is almost certainly going to get very deep and wide, probably enough so to kill the stack anyway. (If you were counting on tail recursion elimination, Python doesn't do that, and it wouldn't help anyway except to maybe knock 1 call out of each loopcount.)

As a side note, much of your code doesn't actually do anything. For example:

```
h_count + 1
```

This evaluates the expression "h_count + 1", then throws away the result. It doesn't store it anywhere, use it for anything, change the value of h_count, or anything else.